# can not delete linked oracle data by using openquery on sql-server with transaction on c# code

Tags: sql-server, oracle, transactions, openquery

I'm trying to delete linked oracle table row on sqlserver
like below

```
BEGIN 
  Declare @SQL nvarchar(2000)

  -- 1. sql server table update     
  update dbo.tb_cost set Request_Date = NULL ,SAP_Number = NULL
  where Serial = @Serial

  -- 2. linked oracle table row delete
  SET @SQL = 'select * from SAPA3.VVT WHERE SERIAL = ''''' + CAST(@Serial AS  char(36)) + ''''''
  SET @SQL = 'DELETE OPENQUERY(SAP, ''' + @SQL + ''')'
  EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
END
```

When I execute this procedure on ssms, It's working. update and delete are all done.

But

When I execute this procedure in my code with transaction, 
Sql server Table is updated. but Oracle data is not deleted.

Here is my code. (c#)

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

try
{
  using (DbConnection conn = db.CreateConnection())
  {
    conn.Open();
    DbTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
      //Create new data
      CostData cost = new CostData();
      cost.Status = "S";
      cost.Serial = Guid.New();

      //SAVE DATA (Excute procedure to insert data to sql server table)
      bool bResult = db.ExecuteNonQuery("dbo.SP_Cost_Save", cost.Status, cost.Serial);

      if (!bResult)
      {
          trans.Rollback();
          return
      }

      //Excute The procedure (update sql server row & delete oracle row) -- this is The procedure
      //I expect update & delete, but delete is not committed
      db.ExecuteNonQuery(trans, "dbo.SP_Cost_Cancel", cost.Serial);

      trans.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      trans.Rollback();
      return
    }
  }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    log('error')
}

return
```

Comment: Have you verified the transaction is the problem, that is, does it work if you don't do it in a transaction? If the transaction *is* the problem, then for starters, leave out do-nothing exception handlers that mask the problem or throw away details. You almost never need to roll back a transaction explicitly; that happens as part of the `using` if you don't commit it. (And while we're on that topic -- wrap the transaction in `using`, it's disposable.)

Comment: thank you for answer to my question  'Jeroen Mostert '. I realized that my question had been wrong. my source and procedure executed like what I want. update & delete both are all done with transaction.